# NSURLConnection giving 200 HTTP response on a URL that is unreachable

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm seeing some odd behavior and looking for some ideas as to what might be causing the issue. I am making NSURLConnection HTTP requests to URLs that are on an internal company network and thus only reachable via VPN. Sometimes the requests fail (as expected) but sometimes they succeed when they shouldn't.

```
- (NSInteger)sendConnectionRequestForURL:(NSURL *)url
                                    error: (NSError *
                                            _Nonnull __autoreleasing *)error
                          didAuthenticate:(BOOL * _Nullable)didAuth {
    // Clear cache
    [[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] removeAllCachedResponses];

    self.connectionResponse = nil;
    self.didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge = NO;

    // Build requests
    NSURLRequest *request =
    [NSURLRequest
    requestWithURL:url
    cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData
    timeoutInterval:TIMEOUT_INTERVAL];

    // Build connection
    NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc]
                                   initWithRequest:request
                                          delegate:self
                                  startImmediately:NO];

    [connection scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop]
                          forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];

    // Start request
    [connection start];
    self.runFlag = YES;
    NSInteger maxIterations = 10000000;
    NSInteger counter = 0;
    while (self.runFlag && counter < maxIterations) {
        NSDate *runTime = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:10];
        [[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] runMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode
                              beforeDate:runTime];
        ++counter;
    }
}
```

There is some processing done afterwards, but that's how the request is created and sent. Here is the response I get:

```
<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x146ee0020> { URL: http://internalurl.local:80/ } { status code: 200, headers {
    "Cache-Control" = "no-cache";
    Connection = close;
    "Content-Encoding" = gzip;
    "Content-Type" = "text/html";
    Date = "Fri, 29 Jan 2016 21:11:15 GMT";
    Expires = "Fri, 29 Jan 2016 21:11:14 GMT";
    Server = someserver;
    "Transfer-Encoding" = Identity;
    Vary = "Accept-Encoding";
} }
```

Any ideas or suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Edit: Just wanted to add that I know NSURLConnection is deprecated with iOS9 but we need to include it in our tests for legacy support. I am having a similar issue with NSURLSession as well.

Comment: Has this application successfully accessed that URL in the past? Does the issue stop if the application is deleted and reinstalled?

Comment: @quellish this website is setup so that HTTP requests *always* fail. I deleted and reinstalled the app and that seems to have fixed the issue; however, it is still peculiar since I have never received a 200 response from that URL

Comment: There are a lot of things that could be causing this based on your description of the problem and environment. I would suggest looking at the data returned when this problem stimulates, especially if there was a network configuration change detected by the system configuration APIs beforehand.